# De duping Table Joined to itself

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table:

```
     ID|ID2
  -----+---
  1234 |56473  
  56473|1234   
  34521|56473  
  35462|23457  
  23457|35462  
  56473|34521
```

As you can see these ids are linked together via a previous join based upon different fields, the combination of these ids repeats itself throughout the table just in a different order

Desired output:

```
     ID|ID2
  -----+---
  1234 |56473
  34521|56473 
  35462|23457
```

Comment: Please read the sqlite tag wiki  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info for a description of how and why to provide a [mre] with this.

Comment: I understand that the input was created by a self join. Please also show the input to that, because it might be much easier to approach there.

Comment: Is it guranteed that the second column is just a reordered version of the first one? If not please extend your sample input to also cover cases where it is not.

Comment: What happens in case the number of entries is odd? What is the desired result in that case? If it cannot happen then please explain why.

Comment: Please describe the desired output in prose, in addition to showing the example. I do not understand the logic behind it, the rules it is based on.

Comment: Would this output also be OK "1234 |56473; 23457|35462; 34521|56473"? If not why not?

Comment: I assume that sorting the left column and only using the lower-valued half does NOT work. Please make sure that the sample data you provide demonstrate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MIN()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#minoreunc) and [`MAX()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc) functions:

```
select distinct
  min(ID, ID2) ID, max(ID, ID2) ID2
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eF3hCATJ9gr6voGbFpvLYF/0).
Results:

```
| ID    | ID2   |
| ----- | ----- |
| 1234  | 56473 |
| 34521 | 56473 |
| 23457 | 35462 |
```